# UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: ) always returns false?

Tags: swift, definition

The question pretty much sums it up. I have checked many different words, and none return true. Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("accessed")
    print(words[indexPath.row])
    if UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: words[indexPath.row]) {
        print("in")
        let ref: UIReferenceLibraryViewController = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: words[indexPath.row])
        self.present(ref, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I am trying to display a definition given a word. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you added a language you need from manage option?

Comment: No, I haven't! That must be the problem, but I am unable to find the option to do that. Where is that option?

Comment: just present the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` without checking. You will find the manage option at the left bottom corner.

Comment: @ATir I'm having the same issue. Were you able to fix it?